# Question on the definition of surface integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, surface-integrals

For a surface S given explicitly as the graph of z = ƒ(x, y), where ƒ is a continuously differentiable function over a region R in the xy-plane, the surface integral of the continuous function G over S is given by the double integral over R.
$$\iint_S G(x,y,z) dS=\iint_R G(x,y,z(x,y))\sqrt{1+f_x^2+f_y^2} dxdy$$

The definition requires that $f$ is continuously differentable, and $G$ is continuous. What are these requirement used for? What if I break the rules? Can anyone give an example or explain it directly? Thanks in advance : )

Comment: for a function to be integrable it should be continuous and to get a derivative of a function it should be differentiable.

Comment: @Jasser But some discontinuous functions are integrable?

Comment: Try to integrate the derivative of the function $f(x) = |x|$ between $[-1,1]$, it should give you $0$. Clearly the derivative of $|x|$ is integrable although it is not derivable at $x=0$.

Comment: Those discontinuous functions are piecewise continuous (I thought this was obvious)@AuriAiur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your surface $S$ is a sphere centered in the origin of coordinates, and you want to evaluate the surface $A$ of the upper part above the plane $z=0$, it is clear that $G=H(z)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function. Although $H$ is discontinuous, your integral will still give the surface of the upper part of the sphere.\

The continuity of $f$ is required to define a normal vector given by the its gradient, but again, the normal vector coes not need to be continuous, i.e. if you have a corner you can always split the surface integral up into each of the sides and compute them as usual.

Comment: You mean that whether G is continuous or not doesn't affect the result? Since H is discontinuous but my integral still give the surface?

Comment: Yes! You are correct.

Comment: But it is only a special case, could you please give a more strict proof? I'm thinking about it for hours. All the references I have require G to be continuous and I don't know why

Comment: I suggest you to read about the space of square integrable functions $L^2$. You will find that a discontinuous function that belongs to $L^2$ is indeed integrable. You have lots of proofs.

Comment: thank you bro : )